# Do open() and read() in python execute the file?

Tags: python, file, malware

If I open a binary or text file in Python with the open and read() commands to be written somewhere else, will it be executed? Could this expose the computer to malware if the file contains malicious code?

Comment: No, just inspecting the contents of such a file should not be harmful, however be careful with what you do to the data

Comment: No. You're just reading the file, not executing it - barring any issues  in how your operating system handles file.

Comment: No.  (With about 99.9999% certainty -- it's theoretically possible that there might be a bug in the OS or Python that would allow code execution when certain sequences of bytes are read from disk, but that would be unprecedentedly bad.)

Answer (score 2):

No, read and open file does not execute the executable file in python. If you want you can read the executable file in binary by adding "b"

open("readfile.txt", "rb")

For executing the py file you need to use "exec" function like

execfile('hello.py')

For executing external exe file there are several ways,where you need to import "os" or "subprocess".

example you can execute file by using the below function.

import os
os.startfile("C:\Documents and Settings\flow_model\flow.exe")